# How to make allow-scripts and allow-same-origin coexist in iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, firefox-addon, sandbox, firefox-addon-webextensions

So i just want to sandbox one html file in iframe and it works as long as there is just `allow-scripts` attribute, but as soon as I add `allow-same-origin` it stops to work because of this:

> Notes about sandboxing:
>   When the embedded document has the same origin as the embedding page, it is strongly discouraged to use both **allow-scripts** and **allow-same-origin**, **as that lets the embedded document remove the sandbox attribute** — making it no more secure than not using the sandbox attribute at all.
>   Sandboxing is useless if the attacker can display content outside a sandboxed iframe — such as if the viewer opens the frame in a new tab. Such content should be also served from a separate origin to limit potential damage.
>   The sandbox attribute is unsupported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier.From:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Code of iframe:

```
<iframe src="index.html" sandbox='allow-scripts allow-same-origin'></frame>
```

I want `allow-same-origin` because I want to use same css in iframe as is in index.html.

Comment: I understand, but is there any other way to sandbox html file so that it keeps it's origin(css in this case)?@SLaks

Comment: sandbox has nothing to do with origin or CSS.

Comment: HTML file:  `<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en" >  
  
<head>  
  
  
  <title>Title</title>  
  <script>  
  ...  
  </script>  
  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
  
</head>  
  
<body>  
  
 
   <p class="text-light" id="something">something</p>  
          <button onclick="function1()" class="btn button- 
 gradient">Listen</button>  
</body>  
</html>  
    
  
  
` This is HTML file that is in src of iframe and if I do not add allow-scripts,   button is not working, by the way it works in chrome flawlessly with sandbox in   manifest file. @SLaks

Comment: Is there another way to sandbox HTML file in this case @SLaks?

Comment: As the error explains, there is no point in sandboxing because you're granting permission to escape the sandbox.

Answer (score 4):

Host the iframe content on a different origin (i.e. a different domain or sub-domain) from the parent page. This will keep the iframe secure when using `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"`.

But either way, CSS does NOT inherit in iframes. In fact, that's the whole purpose of iframes. And you can load the same CSS file in both pages, even without `allow-same-origin` set.